# Extending delegate protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol that I want my classes to confront.

```
protocol myClass: class {
    var delegate: Delegate? { get set }
    var childClasses: [myClass] { get set }
}

protocol Delegate: class {
    func doStuff()
}
```

Problem that I am having is that I want for my classes to have an ability extend existing protocol `Delegate`. Is there a way to do it besides `associatedtype`?

Comment: Could you share example what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is an example of what Iam trying to achieve:
     class ClassA: myClass {
          var delegate: ClassADelegate? { get set }
    }
     protocol ClassADelegate: Delegate {
          func anotherMethod()
    }